# Keras - ValueError: Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` or `(x, y)`. Found: [[[[0.54901963] [0.5372549 ]

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

So I try to train an autoencoder using ImageDataGenerator using this script :

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

batch_size = 128

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split = 0.2)

training_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                     target_size=(105, 105),
                                                     color_mode='grayscale',
                                                     batch_size = batch_size,
                                                     class_mode=None,
                                                     subset='training')
validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                     target_size=(105, 105),
                                                     color_mode='grayscale',
                                                     batch_size = batch_size,
                                                     class_mode=None,
                                                     subset='validation')

history = autoencoder.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, 
                                    epochs=5, 
                                    steps_per_epoch=int(training_generator.samples // batch_size),
                                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                                    validation_steps = int(validation_generator.samples // batch_size),
                                    use_multiprocessing=False)
```

My data directory are like this:

```
real_train_500_2
    |----> train
             |-----> images
```

And here's the summary of my autoencoder model:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 48, 48, 64)        7808      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 24, 24, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 128)       8320      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 24, 24, 64)        8256      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2 (None, 48, 48, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTr (None, 105, 105, 1)       7745      
=================================================================
Total params: 32,129
Trainable params: 32,129
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Here's the complete error message :

```
Found 1375004 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 343750 images belonging to 1 classes.
Epoch 1/5

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-5990e699b664> in <module>
     23                                     validation_data=validation_generator,
     24                                     validation_steps = int(validation_generator.samples // batch_size),
---> 25                                     use_multiprocessing=False)

C:\MyProgramFiles\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

C:\MyProgramFiles\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1730             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1731             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1732             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1733 
   1734     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

C:\MyProgramFiles\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    201                                      'a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` '
    202                                      'or `(x, y)`. Found: ' +
--> 203                                      str(generator_output))
    204                 if x is None or len(x) == 0:
    205                     # Handle data tensors support when no input given

ValueError: Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` or `(x, y)`. Found: [[[[0.54901963]
   [0.5372549 ]
   [0.5294118 ]
   ...
   [0.6117647 ]
   [0.6117647 ]
   [0.63529414]]

  [[0.56078434]
   [0.5529412 ]
   [0.5411765 ]
   ...
   [0.6       ]
   [0.59607846]
   [0.60784316]]

  [[0.5764706 ]
   [0.5647059 ]
   [0.5529412 ]
   ...
   [0.60784316]
   [0.60784316]
   [0.64705884]]

  ...

  [[0.54509807]
   [0.54509807]
   [0.54901963]
   ...
   [0.63529414]
   [0.6156863 ]
   [0.6392157 ]]

  [[0.5254902 ]
   [0.54901963]
   [0.5686275 ]
   ...
   [0.627451  ]
   [0.6       ]
   [0.6       ]]

  [[0.5647059 ]
   [0.54509807]
   [0.56078434]
   ...
   [0.627451  ]
   [0.63529414]
   [0.62352943]]]


 [[[0.5529412 ]
   [0.5686275 ]
   [0.58431375]
   ...
   [0.54509807]
   [0.5764706 ]
   [0.54901963]]

  [[0.56078434]
   [0.5686275 ]
   [0.57254905]
   ...
   [0.5411765 ]
   [0.5764706 ]
   [0.58431375]]

  [[0.56078434]
   [0.56078434]
   [0.5568628 ]
   ...
   [0.54509807]
   [0.5764706 ]
   [0.5294118 ]]

  ...

  [[0.3647059 ]
   [0.37254903]
   [0.3647059 ]
   ...
   [0.36862746]
   [0.37647063]
   [0.33333334]]

  [[0.36078432]
   [0.37647063]
   [0.3803922 ]
   ...
   [0.3529412 ]
   [0.38431376]
   [0.34509805]]

  [[0.36862746]
   [0.3647059 ]
   [0.37254903]
   ...
   [0.3529412 ]
   [0.34901962]
   [0.3372549 ]]]


 [[[0.78823537]
   [0.75294125]
   [0.7686275 ]
   ...
   [0.76470596]
   [0.7686275 ]
   [0.7411765 ]]

  [[0.7725491 ]
   [0.74509805]
   [0.7725491 ]
   ...
   [0.7607844 ]
   [0.76470596]
   [0.7294118 ]]

  [[0.7568628 ]
   [0.7372549 ]
   [0.77647066]
   ...
   [0.75294125]
   [0.75294125]
   [0.7490196 ]]

  ...

  [[0.54509807]
   [0.53333336]
   [0.5372549 ]
   ...
   [0.54901963]
   [0.5294118 ]
   [0.5803922 ]]

  [[0.5294118 ]
   [0.52156866]
   [0.5254902 ]
   ...
   [0.56078434]
   [0.54509807]
   [0.57254905]]

  [[0.5254902 ]
   [0.54509807]
   [0.5568628 ]
   ...
   [0.5058824 ]
   [0.5803922 ]
   [0.53333336]]]


 ...


 [[[0.4039216 ]
   [0.37647063]
   [0.3647059 ]
   ...
   [0.5058824 ]
   [0.48627454]
   [0.5137255 ]]

  [[0.39607847]
   [0.40000004]
   [0.4039216 ]
   ...
   [0.5254902 ]
   [0.52156866]
   [0.43921572]]

  [[0.35686275]
   [0.39607847]
   [0.41176474]
   ...
   [0.5176471 ]
   [0.5294118 ]
   [0.53333336]]

  ...

  [[0.4039216 ]
   [0.41960788]
   [0.42352945]
   ...
   [0.4901961 ]
   [0.48235297]
   [0.4666667 ]]

  [[0.39607847]
   [0.40784317]
   [0.41176474]
   ...
   [0.52156866]
   [0.5019608 ]
   [0.48235297]]

  [[0.3647059 ]
   [0.3921569 ]
   [0.4156863 ]
   ...
   [0.49803925]
   [0.50980395]
   [0.52156866]]]


 [[[0.8431373 ]
   [0.85098046]
   [0.854902  ]
   ...
   [0.9176471 ]
   [0.94117653]
   [0.9490197 ]]

  [[0.8470589 ]
   [0.854902  ]
   [0.86274517]
   ...
   [0.90196085]
   [0.909804  ]
   [0.93725497]]

  [[0.85098046]
   [0.854902  ]
   [0.86666673]
   ...
   [0.909804  ]
   [0.91372555]
   [0.9294118 ]]

  ...

  [[0.8941177 ]
   [0.8745099 ]
   [0.854902  ]
   ...
   [0.9215687 ]
   [0.92549026]
   [0.92549026]]

  [[0.8941177 ]
   [0.8705883 ]
   [0.8470589 ]
   ...
   [0.9490197 ]
   [0.9803922 ]
   [0.8588236 ]]

  [[0.854902  ]
   [0.854902  ]
   [0.89019614]
   ...
   [0.9058824 ]
   [0.9490197 ]
   [0.9058824 ]]]


 [[[0.7019608 ]
   [0.7254902 ]
   [0.70980394]
   ...
   [0.7058824 ]
   [0.72156864]
   [0.7254902 ]]

  [[0.69411767]
   [0.7058824 ]
   [0.69411767]
   ...
   [0.69803923]
   [0.69411767]
   [0.69803923]]

  [[0.69803923]
   [0.69411767]
   [0.6901961 ]
   ...
   [0.69803923]
   [0.69411767]
   [0.7294118 ]]

  ...

  [[0.94117653]
   [0.9176471 ]
   [0.9058824 ]
   ...
   [0.9215687 ]
   [0.92549026]
   [0.8980393 ]]

  [[0.95294124]
   [0.92549026]
   [0.91372555]
   ...
   [0.9176471 ]
   [0.9215687 ]
   [0.9450981 ]]

  [[0.9215687 ]
   [0.9176471 ]
   [0.91372555]
   ...
   [0.9450981 ]
   [0.91372555]
   [0.93725497]]]]
```

I looked for solutions in github and any other else, but it doesn't solve my problem. Because I'm not using any Customized Data generators.
I'm new to keras, any suggestion is a blessing!

Comment: I think you are missing your labels. So you would be tempted to feed in just all the inputs to the generator. But you need two classes anyway, otherwise why build a classifier? :)

Comment: @boomkin Thank you for your response, well this is an autoencoder so I only take the features without any labels. I'm going to transfer some of the layer to my classifier later on after my autoencoder trained with unlabaled data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3923#issuecomment-251185669)

adding this function:

```
def fixed_generator(generator):
    for batch in generator:
        yield (batch, batch)
```

and then implement it to the `.fit_generator` :

```
history = autoencoder.fit_generator(generator=fixed_generator(training_generator), 
                                    epochs=5, 
                                    steps_per_epoch=training_generator.samples // batch_size,
                                    validation_data=fixed_generator(validation_generator),
                                    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
                                    use_multiprocessing=False)
```

This code seems work for me. This issue is also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526362/keras-valueerror-output-of-generator-should-be-a-tuple-x-y-sample-weight-or) in stackoverflow

output:

```
Epoch 1/20
10741/10742 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0069Epoch 1/20
10742/10742 [==============================] - 1645s 153ms/step - loss: 0.0069 - val_loss: 0.0053
Epoch 2/20
10741/10742 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0043Epoch 1/20
10742/10742 [==============================] - 747s 70ms/step - loss: 0.0043 - val_loss: 0.0049
Epoch 3/20
10741/10742 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0041Epoch 1/20
10742/10742 [==============================] - 596s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0041 - val_loss: 0.0047
Epoch 4/20
10740/10742 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0040Epoch 1/20
10742/10742 [==============================] - 590s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0040 - val_loss: 0.0046
Epoch 5/20
10740/10742 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0040Epoch 1/20
10742/10742 [==============================] - 609s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0040 - val_loss: 0.0046
Epoch 6/20
   21/10742 [..............................] - ETA: 5:21 - loss: 0.0040
10741/10742 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0039Epoch 1/20
10742/10742 [==============================] - 594s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0039 - val_loss: 0.0046
Epoch 7/20
10740/10742 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0039Epoch 1/20
10742/10742 [==============================] - 587s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0039 - val_loss: 0.0045
```